# Unable to take screenshot with python selenium and schtasks

Tags: python, selenium, screenshot, windows-task-scheduler

I have the following python code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import time
    import datetime
    i = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    string = str(i)
    fisier = string.replace(":", "-")
    print fisier
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.implicitly_wait(30)
    browser.get('http://www.google.com')
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.save_screenshot(fisier + '.png')
    browser.close()
    browser.quit()
```

I want to save the screenshot with the filename set to date. The above script works perfectly fine, and I get the desired screenshot.

Now I want this script to be run every 5 minutes so I tried with "schtasks" like:

```
    schtasks /Create /SC MINUTE /MO 5 /TN screenshot /TR "C:/python27/screenshot.py"
```

The task gets created successfully, it starts the script every 5 minutes, but it doesn't save the screenshot (script runs fine, no errors).

What can be wrong?

TL'DR : python script takes screenshot, scheduled task with script doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure that it's really doesn't takes screenshots? Maybe it just saves them into different location... Try to set direct folder for screenshot files, like `browser.save_screenshot("/save/it/right/here/" + fisier + '.png')`

Comment: Never thought it might not work if I don't specify direct path. Changed in the script: browser.save_screenshot(fisier + '.png') to browser.save_screenshot('C:/python27' + fisier + '.png') and it works. Thank you @Andersson

Answer (score 0):

`browser.save_screenshot("/save/it/right/here/" + '/fisier' + '.png')`

use the above instead. It works.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answering questions is good but this is just a copy of an old comment and so is not very useful. Answers should provide new explanations and insights into the topic.